# Jquery ajax back button to return on searching page with searched results

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, back

I am making advanced search.. from over here thse searching result showing the listing..

from listing i am going on detail page where i want to add back button clicking on it it will back to my search results page... it is way to implement?

I have tried with hashchange but not succeeed... I thing hash change is depends on div based not on different page.. how should i acheive back button with searching results?

```
function goBack()
{
    alert(location.hash);
    // Bind the event.
    $(window).hashchange(function () {
        // Alerts every time the hash changes!
        alert(location.hash);
    })

    // Trigger the event (useful on page load).
    $(window).hashchange();

}
```

Regards

Comment: hashchange is function in jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function goBack()
{
   window.history.back()
}
```

Comment: window.history.back() can not remains searching criteria .. i want to make search resluts same as it is when i press back button?